# How to execute a command within a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing a script that will continuously broadcast some data to port 30000, so a python udp listener can get the data and insert it into a table, from which I can draw that information and display on a web page.

So, I want to execute

`echo -n -e "\x00\x00\x0A\x00        1      012601234512345\x00" | nc -w1 -u localhost 3000`

in the bash script in a while loop.

This is the bash script I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Running Script'   
a=0  
x=1
while [ $a -le 1 ]
do
  echo 'echo -n -e "\x00\x00\x0A\x00        1      012601234'$x'12345\x00" | nc -w1 -u localhost 30000'
  sleep 5 
  let x=$(($x + 1))
done
```

The x variable is incrementing each time throughout the loop so the data changes each time.

At the moment I am thinking that rather than outputing that as a command to the terminal, it is just coming out as a string. I am very new to bash, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're overthinking it.

Just put the command you want to execute there, without quoting it or `echo`ing it. Replace the variable with `${x}`. Variables will be substituted in double-quoted strings, and the `{}` is there to make sure that your variable is interpreted as `x` and not `x12345`.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Running Script'   
a=0  
x=1
while [ $a -le 1 ]
do
  echo -n -e "\x00\x00\x0A\x00        1      012601234${x}12345\x00" | nc -w1 -u localhost 30000
  sleep 5 
  let x=$(($x + 1))
done
```

Comment: I see what you mean there, but it still doesn't work. With your example, would it output any text when executing the command, or would it be running in the background without outputting any text? If that's the case then it may be working, but I would just need to add in another echo to check it is running each loop. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Scratch that, using the listener I wrote earlier, I can see the information coming in. Thank you very much! :D

Comment: This will also work: `echo -n -e \x00\x00\x0A\x00        1      012601234"$x"12345\x00`

Comment: `§(x)` does not work, probably because the normal brackets refer to a command and not a variable.

Comment: @Timo What do you mean by "does not work"? The script as posted works. Of course `$(x)` does something different than `${x}` – the former is command substitution, the latter is parameter expansion.

Comment: @slhck, I wanted to show that `$(x)` is different to `${x}` in case someone is not aware. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 13):

You are indeed echoing the command instead of executing it.

Bash scripts are executed line by line as commands. So this line:

```
echo 'Running Script'
```

is an exact equivalent of typing `echo 'Running Script'` in shell. Try it yourself: it will output `Running Script`. Conclusion: `echo` will output all its arguments to the terminal.

[image: Screenshot from bash with above command evecuted]

That being said, this line:

```
echo 'echo -n -e "\x00\x00\x0A\x00        1      012601234'$x'12345\x00" | nc -w1 -u localhost 30000'
```

will output `echo -n -e "\x00\x00\x0A\x00        1      012601234'$x'12345\x00" | nc -w1 -u localhost 30000` to the terminal Entire line is executed, argument it outputted.

[image: Second command executed in bash]

It still looks confusing, so let's simplify it a bit: let our command be `echo 'echo -n -e "blah"'`.

[image: blah command ran in bash]

You've told it to output the command, so it has outputted the command. Drop the outer `echo` to execute it instead. As [slhck suggested](https://superuser.com/a/795838/194694), you can make use of the variable by wrapping it with curly braces:

```
echo -n -e "\x00\x00\x0A\x00        1      012601234${x}12345\x00" | nc -w1 -u localhost 30000
```

It will execute the command, but not output it. If you want to output the command, try this:

```
cmd="echo -n -e \"\x00\x00\x0A\x00        1      012601234${x}12345\x00\" | nc -w1 -u localhost 30000"
echo $cmd
$cmd
```

First line assigns your command to a `cmd` variable, second line outputs it and third one executes it. It looks confusing at first, but it's pretty simple: bash will just replace variables before executing a command, so typing variable name will cause its content to be executed.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, it has helped me to understand more fully what I am doing. I really appreciate the time it will have taken you to answer this, and I would vote you up if I had 15 rep :(